# Copying pointers to pointers 'contents' in C

Tags: pointers, malloc, free

I'm having some trouble copying pointers' contents. I'm simply trying this:

```
 char* vigia1; 
 char* vigia2;
```

And..

```
  char* aux = (char*) malloc (strlen (vigia1)+1);
  aux=vigia1;
  vigia1=vigia2;
  vigia2=aux;
  free (aux);
```

*vigia1, vigia2* are pointers to a *char* pointer. They both have a *malloc* greater than their maximum possible size, that's OK.

Since I'm trying to make an order for a list, I need to make this change to order the nodes' content. But I'm getting confused: **after the *free(aux)* , *vigia2* doesn't have any value.** I think I must be pointing *vigia2* to the memory region where *aux* is, region that 'disappear' after the *free*. So what should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers, pointers, bad with them, worse without them

A pointer is a number that stores where in memory sth is stored, with that in mind, let's delve into what you've done there:

```
char* aux = (char*) malloc (strlen (vigia1)+1);
```

Good, you've created space somewhere in a part of the memory called *heap*, and stored the address of the newly created memory space at aux.

```
aux=vigia1;
```

Ops, now you've overwritten the address of the memory space you've "created" with the number stored at vigia1, that happens to be an address to another memory space.

```
vigia1=vigia2;
```

Now you're assinging to vigia1 the value of vigia2, another address of some memory space out there.

```
vigia2=aux;
```

And, by the end of it, you make vigia2 point to the memory region previously pointed by vigia1.

```
free (aux);
```

Now, you're *freeing* the memory pointed by aux. Wait a second, on the line above this one you've just made vigia2 point to *this same address*. No wonder it holds nothing useful :)

Trying to help you with what you want to do:

So long you don't have any constraint that *obliges* you to mantain your list nodes ordered in memory, you don't need to copy the content of the node, just make the pointer of the first node point to the memory region of the second node.

A perfect swap would be:

```
char *aux; // you'll need an aux to make the swap, the normal stuff
aux = vigia1; // now aux points to the same address as vigia1
vigia1 = vigia2; // vigia1 now points to the contents of vigia2
vigia2 = aux; // and now vigia2 points to the content pointed previously by vigia1
/* and tada! the swap is done :D */
```

Comment: I was really messing up the concept there. Thank you so much for your detailed answer! understanding that a pointer is basically a memory address, I solved it saving that memory address of where those pointers where pointing, into a double (double aux;). I don't know if it is the right way to do this, but it worked perfect so far. I really get confused SO easily with pointers!!

Comment: Glad it helped. It's easy to get confused with pointers at the beginning, but you get used to it ;)

Just one question, though: why the downvote without any comment explaining how and why the answer can be improved?

Comment: Sorry I just read. I didn't downvote any answer! I am new on this site. What I've noticed is that other answers are now "0" votes and I have upvoted every one, because all helped. Maybe I am not allowed to upvote all and someone changed it? I don't really know.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning one pointer to another simply copies the value of one pointer to another, i.e., an address.  It doesn't copy what the pointer refers to into another location at a different address.  So yes, you can have N pointers all pointing to the same chunk of memory, but once `free()` is called one of them they are all invalid.

So that means that this:

```
char* aux = (char*) malloc (strlen (vigia1)+1);
aux=vigia1;
```

Is a memory leak.  You `malloc`'d some memory for `aux` and then immediately discarded the address.  There is no way to get it back, no way to `free()` it any longer.

Comment: Excellent. You really helped me too.

Comment: Same here. I UPVOTED all! In fact the up arrow is orange right now and it says "the answer is useful (click to undo)" maybe a moderator changed it? I don't know what can it be, I'm new on the site. If I click again now, it doesn't let me upvote (you last voted on this answer Nov7....). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

What you are making is just pointer assignments. Malloc'ed memory is just getting wasted causing a leak.

```
aux=vigia1; // Makes aux point to the location where vigia1 is pointing to
            // Doesn't copy the contents of vigia1 to malloc'ed memory for aux
```

You need to make deep copy using `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(aux, vigia1);
```

Hope this gives you the hint.

Comment: I think it happened the same to you. If you received a downvote from me: I UPVOTED each answers! Because you've helped me all. In fact the up arrow is orange right now and it says "the answer is useful (click to undo)" maybe a moderator changed it. I don't know what can it be, I'm new on the site. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @LeanDroid No problem. Glad that my answer had helped you to some extent.